# How to get keys from nested dictionary of arbitrary length in Python

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, dictionary, nested

I have a dictionary object in python.  Let's call it as `dict`.   This object could contain another dictionary which may in turn contain another dictionary and so on.

```
     dict = { 'k': v, 'k1': v1, 'dict2':{'k3': v3, 'k4':v4} , 'dict3':{'k5':v5, dict4:{'k6':v6}}}
```

This is just an example.  Length of outermost dictionary could be anything.  I want to extract keys from such dictionary object in following two ways :

1. get list of only keys.

   ```
   [k,k1,k2,k3,k4,k5,k6]
   ```
2. get list of keys and its parent associated dictionary so something like this :

   ```
   outer_dict_keys = [k ,dict2, dict3]
   dict2_keys = [k3,k4]
   dict3_keys = [k5, dict4]
   dict4_keys = [k6]
   ```

Outermost dictionary `dict` length is always changing so I can not hard code anything.

What is best way to achieve above result ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a mix of iteration and tail recursion.  After quoting undefined names, making spacing uniform, and removing 'k2' from the first result, I came up with the code below.  (Written and tested for 3.4, it should run on any 3.x and might on 2.7.)  A key thing to remember is that the iteration order of dicts is essentially random, and varies with each run.  Recursion as done here visit sub-dicts in depth-first rather than breadth-first order.  For dict0, both are the same,  But if dict4 were nested in dict2 rather than dict3, they would not be.

```
dict0 = {'k0': 0, 'k1': 1, 'dict2':{'k3': 3, 'k4': 4},
         'dict3':{'k5': 5, 'dict4':{'k6': 6}}}

def keys(dic, klist=[]):
    subdics = []
    for key in sorted(dic):
        val = dic[key]
        if isinstance(val, dict):
            subdics.append(val)
        else:
            klist.append(key)
    for subdict in subdics:
        keys(subdict, klist)
    return klist

result = keys(dict0)
print(result, '\n', result == ['k0','k1','k3','k4','k5','k6'])

def keylines(dic, name='outer_dict', lines=[]):
    vals = []
    subdics = []
    for key in sorted(dic):
        val = dic[key]
        if isinstance(val, dict):
            subdics.append((key,val))
        else:
            vals.append(key)
    vals.extend(pair[0] for pair in subdics)
    lines.append('{}_keys = {}'.format(name, vals))
    for subdict in subdics:
        keylines(subdict[1], subdict[0], lines)
    return lines

result = keylines(dict0)
for line in result:
    print(line,)
print()
expect = [
        "outer_dict_keys = ['k0', 'k1', 'dict2', 'dict3']",
        "dict2_keys = ['k3', 'k4']",
        "dict3_keys = ['k5', 'dict4']",
        "dict4_keys = ['k6']"]
for actual, want in zip(result, expect):
    if actual != want:
        print(want)
        for i, (c1, c2) in enumerate(zip(actual, want)):
            if c1 != c2:
                print(i, c1, c2)
```